# R doesn't omit base level of factor interaction with a numeric, if the main effect of the numeric comes from a function

Tags: r, formula, regression, interaction

I know this issue can be circumvented by generating pre-computed transformations, but I would really like to use the formula functionality of R. Here is a reproducible example of my problem:

Generate (correlated) toy data:

```
set.seed(123)
test<-data.frame(x=rnorm(100,1,.5),z=factor(sample(c('a','b','c'),100,T)))
test$y<-.3*test$x+0*(test$z=='a')-.07*(test$z=='b')-.15*(test$z=='c')+rnorm(100,0,.1)
```

Run a linear model:

```
> lm(y ~ x + z, test)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + z, data = test)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x           zb           zc  
    0.02453      0.27484     -0.08279     -0.12868
```

Looks good. The first factor level 'a' is omitted just like it should be. Now include an interaction between numeric x and factor z:

```
> lm(y ~ x + z + z:x, test)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + z + z:x, data = test)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x           zb           zc         x:zb         x:zc  
   0.037008     0.262650    -0.134938    -0.118896     0.049068    -0.009225 
        lm(y ~ poly(x,2) + z:x, test)
```

Everything is still fine. Now use the 'poly' function to add a quadratic transformation of x:

```
> lm(y ~ poly(x, 2) + z + z:x, test)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2) + z + z:x, data = test)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  poly(x, 2)1  poly(x, 2)2           zb           zc         za:x         zb:x         zc:x  
    0.33928      1.23017     -0.18029     -0.15478     -0.15574     -0.02749      0.04165           NA
```

And here it is. Instead of excluding the first level of z 'a' in the interaction term, it is included along the two other levels. Now, the za:x ist 'aliased' because the model would of course be singular with all three factor levels included. This is bad, because functions like 'vif' from the 'car' package don't work:

```
> vif(lm(y ~ poly(x,2) + z + z:x, test))
Error in vif.lm(lm(y ~ poly(x, 2) + z + z:x, test)) : 
  there are aliased coefficients in the model
```

I tried things like y ~ poly(x,2) + z + z:poly(x,1) or y ~ poly(x,2) + z + relevel(z, ref='a'):x but nothing seemed to work. Is this a bug or could someone explain this result? Is there a way to avoid this problem and still use the formula functionality in the way I intended? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because formulas allow you to use any function, there's no way for R to know what functions will return values equal to other values already in the equation. There is no special coding for `poly()` that exists.

If you want to just include an `x` and an `x^2` term, you could do

```
lm(formula = y ~ x + I(x^2) + z + z:x, data = test)
```

avoiding the use of `poly()` all together. You simply have to be more careful in the construction of the formula.

Comment: Aren't `y ~ x + I(x^2) + z + z:x` and `y ~ x + I(x^2) + z + z:x` different?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you typed the same thing twice, bit if you mean that `y~poly(x,2)` and `y~x+I(x^2)` are different then, yes, they are because `poly()` created orthogonal values by default, but it's the same as  `y~poly(x,2,raw=TRUE)`

Comment: @MrFlick: does R have to know what values the function will return? Why does the inclusion or exclusion of x affect the format of z:x? Why doesn't R behave consistently, i. e. using the first level of z as the base? I(x^2) does work in this case, but poly() was just a simple example of other things I would like to do, such as bs()...

Comment: It has to do with model identifiability and over-specification when using reference level coding. When both `x` and `x:z` are in the model, R recognizes the redundancy and removes the un-estimable parameter. When you hide the `x` in a function call, R can't do that cleaning for you. If you don't understand the statical modeling, you might want to be asking this question over at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: @MrFlick: I do understand the statistical background and am familiar with the mathematical constraints of linear models. I was just hoping that there was a way to tell R how to do that 'cleaning' when functions are involved and the built in mechanism fails to remove the redundant vectors. Thanks for helping me realize that this doesn't seem to be the case.